# can "interchanging usb ports of expansion hdd disks when comp on suspension" damage them?

Tags: hard-disk, external-hdd, usb-device

I have two seagate expansion drives, the first one is 3.5'' 1.5TB and the second one is 2.5'' 2TB. 
The latter is partitioned and I installed Ubuntu 16.04 in it.

The day before I booted up with the latter expansion disk and plugged in the first expansion disk to move documents in it. It's rather old disk, I bought it about 7 years ago, it acts up sometimes, and makes click-cluck noise. I needed to plug in receiver of wireless mouse so I suspended the comp and changed the usb ports.

First Position:
`3.5''Expansion--->USB PORT1, 2.5''Expansion--->USB PORT2`

Final Position: `3.5''Expansion--->USB PORT2, 2.5''Expansion--->USB PORT1`

And I let it resume,  I should have lost my mind, as you know it resumed but  froze immediately, because it could not read and write to `2.5''Expansion--->USB PORT2`. I did a hard boot, it loaded the session but did not detected the old `3.5''Expansion` , I shut down the comp because it was late at night.

Yesterday I started the comp and tried to open `3.5''Expansion` but it wouldn't detect it. I tried to unplug and plug the power cable of `3.5''Expansion`, none didn't work. I also tried it on Windows, it only detected it as a usb device, but can not view the content. I also checked it on drivers list in `computer management`, it's not listed.
On Ubuntu it's listed in `/dev/sdc`. I tried to mount it like

```
 sudo mount /dev/sdc /mnt
```

but it hangs

Now I fear that it blew up when I interchanged usb ports.

How can I know about what happened to my `3.5''Expansion`?

EDIT: output of `dmesg`

EDIT2: In Windows  right-click  Computer->Manage-> in the left panel under Storage -> Disk Management, clicking  it and on the right panel my USB HDD appears but it is shrinked around 3GB. When I right click  it, menu items grayed out. 
When I restarted it asks me `gpt or mbr` I tried each one respectively, but both failed to start the drive.

```
[ 6751.442410] usb 2-5: new high-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
[ 6751.573306] usb 2-5: New USB device found, idVendor=0bc2, idProduct=3300
[ 6751.573316] usb 2-5: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 6751.573322] usb 2-5: Product: Desktop         
[ 6751.573328] usb 2-5: Manufacturer: Seagate 
[ 6751.573333] usb 2-5: SerialNumber: 00000000    
[ 6751.573984] usb-storage 2-5:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 6751.578845] scsi host6: usb-storage 2-5:1.0
[ 6752.576847] scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Seagate  Desktop          0130 PQ: 0 ANSI: 4
[ 6752.582198] sd 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
[ 6752.582847] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] 8089949 512-byte logical blocks: (4.14 GB/3.86 GiB)
[ 6752.583607] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
[ 6752.583621] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 2f 08 00 00
[ 6752.584464] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] No Caching mode page found
[ 6752.584475] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 6752.588580] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 6752.588593] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[ 6752.588602] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Add. Sense: Logical block address out of range
[ 6752.588610] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00
[ 6752.588617] blk_update_request: critical target error, dev sdc, sector 0
[ 6752.588626] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc, logical block 0, async page read
```

Comment: No should not break the hardware.

Comment: @richard thank you for responding. I feel better and sensible

Comment: In general, if your HDD "acts up" and makes clicking noises, it's high time to run `smartctl` on it to see if it's about to fail, and make a backup. It may be too late to do that now, though. But you can still find out how bad it is: Unplug all external disks and boot. Plug in the bad HDD, and post the end of `dmesg` resp. syslog after the "new USB ... device" line. If it appears as `/dev/sdc` etc., run `smartctl -a /dev/sdc` on it (as root) and post the output.

Comment: @dirkt Thank you for your help. I just posted the `dmesg` output. Some suggest extracting harddisk in the box, and plug it into a computer.

Comment: The total capacity is wrong, so something is severely broken, and I'm not surprised the read doesn't succeed. What is the output of `smartctl -a /dev/sdc`? Taking it out of the enclosure, and directly connecting it via SATA *can* help if it's the USB-SATA-bridge which is broken for some reason. It won't help if the harddisk is broken, but it's worth a try. But check the SMART stuff first.

Comment: @dirkt I just added Windows results

Comment: @dirkt `sudo smartctl -a /dev/sdc` hangs :( I can not stop it with `ctrl-c`

Comment: Ok, so it's not only bad sectors. Try taking it out of the enclosure and connect it directly to SATA, then look at the SMART results. If that also fails, the microcontroller on the HDD is broken. If there was *important* data on the HDD, you can try getting a second-hand similar model and using this as controller. Otherwise, just write it off and get a new one.